# How do i do initialization only once in rails, everytime the app is started?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following ruby file in the initializers

`webApp::Application.registration.post(....);`

that does a post action. How do i make this happen after rails initializes everything {just want to prevent doing a post every time on initialization}

Comment: I don't understand; you want this to run once, period, and never again? What's it doing? What's the purpose? An initializer seems a bad place for something that only ever happens once.

Comment: If you only want to run something once, ever, or just on demand, it should just be a rake task or something like that. If you want it to run just once every time rails starts, then it's a initializer. Not sure which one you are after...